# ERROR: relation "idn_oauth2_user_consent" does not exist

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I used the https://github.com/wso2/docker-is projet to upgrade my previous wso2is 5.11.0 docker, to the latest wso2is 6.1.0.

When running the docker image, the wso2 server starts on the same ports and the user interface with the default super admin user works perfectly fine.

I have a service provider that i used for oauth2 authentication using Postman, this works fine in version 5.11.0, but in version 6.1.0 thanks to some debug logs, i can see this long error message during the authentication cinematic :

```
TID: [-1234] [oauth2] [2023-08-30 07:58:51,502] [a09ede89-1b16-4294-b422-680ce83e7a15] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint} - Server error occurred while performing authorization org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthSystemException: Error occurred while checking user has already approved the consent required OAuth scopes.
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.isUserAlreadyApproved(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:3056)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.doUserAuthorization(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:2401)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.handleSuccessfulAuthentication(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.handleAuthenticationResponse(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:892)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.authorize(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:283)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:222)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.filter.AuthorizationHeaderFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationHeaderFilter.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
.
.
.
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2ScopeServerException: Error occurred while checking whether user : 1a1fb82a-a2c1-435f-9970-1a953b238d40 is already consented for all scopes for application : ffc58bdc-3ffa-45db-8b26-17241a4e80e6 in tenant with Id : -1234.
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService.hasUserProvidedConsentForAllRequestedScopes(OAuth2ScopeService.java:589)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.util.EndpointUtil.isUserAlreadyConsentedForOAuthScopes(EndpointUtil.java:837)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.authz.OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.isUserAlreadyApproved(OAuth2AuthzEndpoint.java:3054)
        ... 69 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.IdentityOAuth2ScopeConsentException: Error occurred while retrieving scope consents for userId : 1a1fb82a-a2c1-435f-9970-1a953b238d40 and appId : ffc58bdc-3ffa-45db-8b26-17241a4e80e6 and tenantId : -1234
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.OAuthUserConsentedScopesDAOImpl.getUserConsentForApplication(OAuthUserConsentedScopesDAOImpl.java:81)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.CacheBackedOAuthUserConsentedScopesDAOImpl.getUserConsentForApplication(CacheBackedOAuthUserConsentedScopesDAOImpl.java:44)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService.hasUserProvidedConsentForAllRequestedScopes(OAuth2ScopeService.java:578)
        ... 71 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "idn_oauth2_user_consent" does not exist
  Position: 62
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:481)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:401)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:118)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.dao.OAuthUserConsentedScopesDAOImpl.getUserConsentForApplication(OAuthUserConsentedScopesDAOImpl.java:63)
        ... 73 more
```

It says that the relation idn_oauth2_user_consent does not exists in the database. So i was wondering if there is a command to run after updating wos2is that will upgrade any changes in the database, or if it should have run during the first execution of the docker image ?

Comment: For more informations this is the redirect after the authentication:

http://localhost:4200?error_description=Server+error+occurred+while+performing+authorization&state=4d4c15bc4a89618cbc69d87544b5434e51738295ba23bc88ab9c80ff84dbcf5c&error=server_error